# find second largest in the list of numbers

Tags: python, arrays

I have to find the second largest number and largest number from the list by divide and conquer algorithm. The problem is that everything is right except the part that I use indices like a and b. Because it works faster. Cost cheaper. Do not need rewrite code or send other codes and approaches. Just help me please to fix it if u can.. Any helps any ideas welcome. Thanks

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python2.7

def two_max(arr,a,b):
      n = len(arr)
      if n==2: 
          if arr[0]<arr[1]: 
             return (arr[1], arr[0])
          else:
             return (arr[0], arr[1])

      (greatest_left, sec_greatest_left) = two_max(arr,a (a+b)/2)
      (greatest_right, sec_greatest_right) = two_max(arr,(a+b)/2,b)
      if greatest_left < greatest_right: 
          greatest = greatest_right
          if greatest_left < sec_greatest_left: 
              return (greatest, sec_greatest_left)
          else:
              return (greatest, greatest_left)
      else:
          greatest = greatest_left
          if greatest_right < sec_greatest_right: # Line 4
              return (greatest, sec_greatest_right)
          else:
              return (greatest, greatest_right)
```

Comment: fix your indentation, the above is a mess.

Comment: Fix your indentation. Correct indentation is critical in Python.

Comment: I would just use sort/sorted and an index. CPU time is much cheaper than my time. Also, python's core sequences are [*lists*](http://docs.python.org/3.3/tutorial/introduction.html#lists), not arrays.

Comment: Anybody? What is indentation? What I need to fix

Comment: This sounds like homework.  I didn't look at your algorithm in detail, but I noticed that you're using (a+b)/2 twice; the second use should probably be (a+b)/2 + 1.  If that still doesn't fix the problem, you may want to step through it with a debugger like winpdb (which is cross platform, despite the name).

Comment: If this isn't homework, you probably should just sort instead of using a divide and conquer algorithm.  Or you could use my nest module, but for m=2, nest is a bit heavyweight: http://stromberg.dnsalias.org/~strombrg/treap/

Comment: @Katty indentation refers to how many spaces each line has at the beginning.  With python, you use indentation to indicate blocks of code.  See for example http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.1/ref/indentation.html

Comment: Indentation is the whitespace (tabs, spaces) on the left of your code.  If it isn't consistent, or if it doesn't reflect the intended structure of your control flow, the python interpreter will give an error or produce incorrect results.

Comment: If you don't even know what indentation is, you need to go back to the start of your course or tutorial and read more carefully; it's going to be way too hard for you to do anything as advanced as debugging recursive functions without knowing the basics.

Comment: Also, that `a (a+b)/2` is going to try to call the number `a` as a function, which isn't likely to work well.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you do it that way:

```
>>> def getIlargest(arr, i):
        if (i <= len(arr) and i > 0):
            return sorted(arr)[-i]

>>> a = [1,3,51,4,6,23,53,2,532,5,2,6,7,5,4]      
>>> getIlargest(a, 2)
53
```

---

**I took it one step further and tested 3 methods:**

1. Using counting sort - `getIlargestVer2`
2. Using python `sorted` function - `getIlargestVer1`
3. Using heap - `heapIlargest` as @abarnert suggested.

**The results:**

for arrays in sizes from 1 to ~5000 `sorted` is  the best, for larger arrays the `heapq.nlargest` usage is the winner:

*plot for arrays in sizes between `[1*150, 55*150]`:*

[image]

*Full scan between array in sizes of [1*150, 300*150]:*

[image]

The code I used is the following, the 3 methods implementation is in `setup` string:

```
setup = """

import heapq, random

a = random.sample(xrange(1<<30), 150)
a = a * factor

class ILargestFunctions:

    # taken from [wiki][3] and was rewriting it.
    def counting_sort(self, array, maxval):
        m = maxval + 1
        count = {}
        for a in array:
            if count.get(a, None) is None:
                count[a] = 1
            else:
                count[a] += 1
        i = 0
        for key in count.keys():
            for c in range(count[key]):
                array[i] = key
                i += 1
        return array

    def getIlargestVer1(self, arr, i):
         if (i <= len(arr) and i > 0):
              return sorted(arr)[-i]

    def getIlargestVer2(self, arr, i):
         if (i <= len(arr) and i > 0):
              return self.counting_sort(arr, max(arr))[-i]

    def heapIlargest(self, arr, i):
        if (i <= len(arr) and i > 0):
            return heapq.nlargest(i,arr)

n = ILargestFunctions() 

"""
```

And the main line triggers the performance counting and plots the collected data is in:

```
import timeit
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

if __name__ == "__main__":
    results = {}
    r1 = []; r2 = []; r3 = [];
    x = np.arange(1,300,1)
    for i in xrange(1,300,1):
        print i
        factorStr = "factor = " + str(i) + ";"
        newSetupStr = factorStr + setup
        r1.append(timeit.timeit('n.getIlargestVer1(a, 100)', number=200, setup=newSetupStr))
        r2.append(timeit.timeit('n.getIlargestVer2(a, 100)', number=200, setup=newSetupStr))
        r3.append(timeit.timeit('n.heapIlargest(a, 100)', number=200, setup=newSetupStr))
        results[i] = (r1,r2,r3)
    p1 = plt.plot(x, r1, 'r', label = "getIlargestVer1")
    p2 = plt.plot(x, r2, 'b' , label = "getIlargestVer2")
    p3 = plt.plot(x, r3, 'g' , label = "heapIlargest")
    plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1), loc=1, borderaxespad=0.)
    plt.show()
```

Comment: Yeah I know. But requirements:( So I need to fix it somehow ;(

Comment: If you really want to do this, why sort the whole array? It's a lot faster, and a little simpler, to just use `heapq.nlargest` (assuming small `i`… which is a reasonable assumption given that the OP specifically only asked about the case where i==1).

Comment: @0x90: `b = a * 1000`, `%timeit heapq.nlargest(2, b)[1]` says 1.74ms. `%timeit sorted(b)[-1]` says 3.3ms. For longer arrays, the disparity just gets larger. Why? The heapq solution is clearly O(n log i) time; the sorted solution is O(n log n). If i is a small constant like 2, and n is of any size large enough that performance matters at all (even just 15000), the heap will be faster. (Also, it uses O(i) space instead of O(n)…)

Comment: @abarnert the weird thing is the counting sort is the worst. Please see my updated answer, and checkout the breakpoint which your suggestion is better than mine.

Comment: @0x90: When testing algorithmic complexity differences, you really need a broader scale (or, better, a logarithmic scale). Also, you need to test for different `i` values, not just different `n` values. But it's a good start.

Comment: @0x90: Also, your `counting_sort` doesn't actually sort—or, rather, it  sorts into the arbitrary key order of a dictionary, which isn't very useful. The usual implementation is a list `[0 for _ in range(maxval)]`. (What if `maxval` is huge, like your `1<<30`? Then you shouldn't be using a counting sort. The whole point is that it's efficient for sorting small integer keys, as it says in the very first sentence of the page you linked. A counting sort is O(n + maxval), and so maxval is > O(n log n) this is a terrible tradeoff.)

Answer (score 1):

The biggest problem is that you never get any closer to your recursive base case.

The base case is `len(arr) == 2`. But every time you call yourself, you just pass `arr` as-is:

```
  (greatest_left, sec_greatest_left) = two_max(arr,a,(a+b)/2)
  (greatest_right, sec_greatest_right) = two_max(arr,(a+b)/2,b)
```

(Note that I'm guessing on the comma in the first one, because as you posted it, you're actually calling the number `a` as a function, which is unlikely to do anything useful…)

So, either your base case should take `a` and `b` into account, like this:

```
if b-a == 2:
    if arr[a]<arr[a+1]:
        return (arr[a+1], arr[a])
    else:
        return (arr[a], arr[a+1])
```

… or you should send a slice of `arr` instead of the whole thing—in which case you don't need `a` and `b` in the first place:

```
  (greatest_left, sec_greatest_left) = two_max(arr[:len(a)/2])
  (greatest_right, sec_greatest_right) = two_max(arr[len(a)/2:])
```

Either one will fix your first problem. Of course the function still doesn't *work* for most inputs. In fact, it only works if the length of the list is a power of two.

If that isn't a good enough hint for how to fix it: What happens if `b-a` is 3? Obviously you can't split it into two halves, both of which are of size 2 or greater. So, you'll need to write another base case for `b-a == 1`, and return *something* that will make the rest of the algorithm work.

Answer (score 0):

@0x90 has the right idea, but he got it reversed.

```
def find_i_largest_element(seq, i):
    if (i <= len(seq) and i > 0):
        s = sorted(seq, reverse=True)
        return s[i-1]
```

By the way, is this a homework assignment? If so, what's the whole idea behind the algorithm you have to use?